# password and username validation with some condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have to create code that validates whether a password:

- Contains at least 1 number
- Contains at least 1 capital letter
- Contains at least 1 lowercase letter
- Contains at least 1 special symbol

and again ask the username and password (the previous one that we entered) if enter the wrong one after 3rd attempt it will print account blocked! (can someone help to fix my code please)

```py
import re
def main():
    
    username = 'qqq'
    password = '12q@3A'
    
    reg = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!#%*?&]"
        # compiling regex 
    pat = re.compile(reg)
    # searching regex
    mat = re.search(pat, password)
    # validating conditions 
    if mat: 
        print("Password is valid.")
        userInput = input("What is your username?\n")

        if userInput == username:
            for i in range (3,0,-1):
                userinput = input("Password?\n")   
                if userinput == password:
                    break
                else:
                    print("That is the wrong password and try again")
            if i==1:
                print("Account BLOCKED")
            else:
                print(" You have succe")
    else:
        print("That is the wrong username.")
else: 
    print("Password invalid !!")

# Driver Code    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Please be specific.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: https://pypi.org/project/zxcvbn-python/

Comment: Passwords should be hashed anyway... enforcing these rules without hashing password is useless

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there are already mature libraries for the task. Also, **never** store passwords as plaintext.

This script will ask user 3 times for correct password, if user fails to enter valid password, print `Account blocked!`:

```
import re

def check(password):
    """ Return True if password

        Contains at least 1 number *AND*
        Contains at least 1 capital letter *AND*
        Contains at least 1 small letter *AND*
        Contains at least 1 special symbol

        False otherwise
    """

    return bool(re.search(r'\d', password) and
                re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) and
                re.search(r'[a-z]', password) and
                re.search(r'[@$!%*#?&]', password))

username = input('Please enter your username: ')

for attempt in range(1, 4):
    password = input('Please enter your password: ')
    if check(password):
        print('Password is OK!')
        break
    print('Invalid password, attempts left {}'.format(3 - attempt))
else:
    print('Account blocked!')
```

Prints (for example):

```
Please enter your username: Andrej
Please enter your password: we
Invalid password, attempts left 2
Please enter your password: wew
Invalid password, attempts left 1
Please enter your password: wew
Invalid password, attempts left 0
Account blocked!
```

---

Or:

```
Please enter your username: Andrej
Please enter your password: A1@a
Password is OK!
```